# Setting directory from Exchange headers in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I have a camel DSL route with a Camel processor that determines a location to send a file to. The path is saved to a header in the Exchange so that it is passed back to the route. I want to use this header value (the path) in my route but I am receiving the following error:

"*Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.*"

When I use the fileName option this creates a file as the last directory from the path, whereas I want this to be a directory but there is no option like *directoryName*

The **to** section of the route is below, where the **fileLocation** is picked up from an external properties file.

```
.to("file://"+fileLocation+"/${in.header."+AppConstants.DIRECTORYLOCATION+"}?
autoCreate=true&delay=3000");
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might try the recipient list EIP per this [camel FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).

Comment: Thanks, that has sorted it!

Comment: Great, I'll leave my comment but also make it an 'answer' then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the recipient list EIP per this [camel FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).

Comment: What about a dynamic URI in "from"?